# print 999 line in output screen

Tags: c++, console

this code print but i need see all line with scroll

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    for (int k=1 ;k<1000;k++)
        cout<<k<<"\n";
    getch();

}
```

i write in windows seven

when compile and see result only 300 line  i see   701-999 
butt i need see all line 1-999

Comment: namespaces and streams suggest that it is not c but c++ question?

Comment: how else do you expect the output would be?

Comment: @Vladimir - I agree - changed the tag

Comment: Please explain what output you're expecting.

Comment: 1) conio.h is not standard c or c++ header 2) main returns int, not void

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Linux:

```
g++ filename.cpp -o filename.out
./filename.out | less
```

I don't use Windows, so I can't say if there is an equivalent.

Comment: Windows' rough equivalent would be `more`. But both solutions are OS-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling of the output is a feature of the console window itself. If your console window doesn't support scrolling, you won't get it with your code, unless you reimplement the console window yourself.

Beside that, your code correctly writes out 999 lines. I would however replace `"\n"` with `endl`.

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output to a file and view the file with a program that has paging capabilities such as `less`, eg. `./a.out > test.txt; less test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Typing

```
./yourprogram | more
```

after compiling it should do the trick. There's no other way to do this, unless you pause your output programatically. You can also use

```
system("pause");
```

in your code after every 50 lines or so, but this is [not recommended](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) and works on Windows/DOS only.

Comment: your recommendation is {DOS,Windows}-specific

Answer (score 0):

In addition to misha's answer, you can use more in a Windows terminal.

```
MyProgram | more
```

more is also a Unix command, but I think DOS's more works more like the Unix less (which lets you go up as well as down thorugh the output) iirc.

Comment: Windows more only lets you go forward, not backward. In this case, more is less.